Japanese adaptations of american franchises, are they on topic?
This is the second one I come across. The first one I didnt care (Isekai Suicide Squad) , but this one I do (Terminator Zero) . The animation is made in Japan and it's in japanese language, the script is japanese, but the original story concept clearly is american. Are they considered "anime" or "partially anime" as for being on topic?

I'd recon yes: What is our current stance on questions about peripheral anime topics

Anime and manga inspired production are on-topic. What is anime/manga and what isn't anime/manga remains a subjective topic that divides the fandom as a whole, depend on who you ask.
However, we're not in the business to tell you what to think on the topic, you're free to draw the line where you see fit. However there are places where the line blurs. As long as it's within reason. As long as it's related to primarily anime and manga related or inspired it should be fair game. Discussions about live action adaptations however might be better suited for another site like Movies and TV.
MAL's database has certain rules for what is anime. It's summed up in brief as:

Shows where all work, aside from the animation, was done outside of Japan/Korea/China (e.g. directing, script, etc.). For example, if a US company outsources only the animation of a particular work to Japan, it will not be included in our database.

They are them and we are us. We're not as strict here and we open questions to productions and media that are not only anime and manga from Japan, but also anime and manga inspired media from other countries. It you're unsure just drop and line on this meta site, we can have a discussion about it.

Many anime websites are filled today with chinese animations. Are they on topic?

If they are anime-styled yes. Kings's Avatar, Link Click, etc. Non-cel shaded 3d animation are borderline, but acceptable. Live-action stop-motion shows like Thunderbolt Fantasy (it's a joint Taiwan Japanese production) are acceptable as they are considered a full form of animation. Anime itself in Japanese refers to any type of animation, in the West the term is used to refer to a specific style of anime. There are exceptions and places where the line blurs. Questions about the Simpsons is off topic, questions about the Death Note Treehouse of Horror episode are on topic.
